# kafka + which files should created under kafka-logs

Tags: apache-kafka

usually after kafka cluster scratch installation I saw this files under /data/kafka-logs ( kafka broker logs. where all topics should be located )

```
ls -ltr 
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop    0 Jan  9 10:07 cleaner-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop   57 Jan  9 10:07 meta.properties
drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka hadoop 4096 Jan  9 10:51 _schemas-0
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop   17 Jan 10 07:39 recovery-point-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop   17 Jan 10 07:39 replication-offset-checkpoint
```

but on some other Kafka scratch installation we saw the folder - /data/kafka-logs is empty

is this indicate on problem ?

note - we still not create the topics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure when each checkpoint file is created (though, they track log cleaner and replication offsets), but I assume that the meta properties is created at broker startup.

Otherwise, you would see one folder per Topic-partition, for example, looks like you had one topic created, `_schemas`.

If you only see one partition folder out of multiple brokers, then your replication factor for that topic is set to 1